# Displaying nothing on device ready in apache cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I have called the BindUsers function in onDeviceReady, but it is showing nothing while debugging.

I have written this in index.js and I have called this on index.html. But still it is showing nothing. But when I am testing it as a website it's displaying properly. I have tested it by making a website in asp.

```
function onDeviceReady() {        
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);
    BindUsers();
};

//The BindUsers begins here

function BindUsers() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', // Method type
        url: 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=the-hindu&apiKey=1f9da58adc9f4197bc26b657821e0722',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //alert(data.articles.title);
            if (data.articles.length > 0) {
                var articles = data.articles;
                for (var key in articles) {
                    //alert(articles[key]['title']);
                    $("#tblUsers").append("<tr> </tr><tr><td ><img src='"
                        + articles[key]['urlToImage'] + "' class='img' ></td></tr> <tr></td><td class='ttlhead'><span class='title'>"
                        + articles[key]['title'] + "</span></td></tr><tr><td ><p class='content'>"
                        + articles[key]['description'] + "</p><a href='"
                        + articles[key]['url'] + "' class='content'>Continue..</a></td></tr><tr><td >"
                        + articles[key]['publishedAt']
                        + "</td></tr>");
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Sorry');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you'll have to be a bit more specific than "showing nothing". Which part is failing exactly? Is the ajax call successful? Does it return what you expect? Are there any console errors? Does the element tblUsers exist in your page? You say you've debugged it but then don't say anything useful about the results of the debugging.

Comment: Yes.My ajax is returning that what i am expecting in asp website.and tblUsers is also there in index.html.

Comment: If that's entirely true then it's really very hard to see what could be the problem. In the scenario you've just described, the code should run ok. So as far as I can see, either your description is inaccurate, or the code above is inaccurate. Can you show the relevant HTML, please?

Comment: I got the solution.Thanks for responding @ADyson.Now its coming.

Comment: That's great, glad you solve it. It would help future readers if you post your solution as an answer then we all understand what the issue is. Also others can then upvote it etc if they wish.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your app immediately tries to get some remote JSON. Are you trying this on iOS? If so you probably need to allow arbitrary loads in your plist, e.g.:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: No I am trying for android.

Comment: Then you might need to ensure your config.xml has permissions. e.g.: <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />